# Ionic framework, keyboard overlaps form

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an Ionic app. Everything looks smooth and clean until I tap an input. The keyboard that displays is too big, so I cannot see my form anymore. What am I supposed to do in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps easiest would be to hide some stuff here and there using built in ionic class which hides element when soft keyboard is present.

```
<div class="hide-on-keyboard-open">
  Some stuff which is irrelevant and will save some space when hidden:)
</div>
```

It works for me as native iOS app and when run on Safari from iPad.

Take a look at documentation:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/